# How to change the log level for logs coming from NestJs itself?

Tags: nestjs

I noticed that NestJS is using the `info` logging level for anything related to its internal operations. This is too "loud" in my opinion, and clutters my logs. I'd like these internal operations to use `debug` or `trace`. I want `info` to be used only for what matters - my app's business logic. How can I achieve this?

I don't think that simply overriding the internal logger is the solution here. I do not want to make any `info` log to log as `debug` / `trace` - only those coming from NestJs's internal operations.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to override the logger - you already know the answer. It's not configurable unless you change the source code.